# Изменение размеров изображения в html

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте! Задача стоит такая: нужно, что бы изображение на html странице плавно увеличивалось в размере, а затем уменьшалось и так покругу. Кому не сложно, поделитесь кодом)

Comment: ЗЫ javascript  должен по времени или просто при наведении ? 

Comment: Вообще или при наведении или при открытии страницы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только я всёравно ничего не понял) Если не сложно и не лень можно полностью код `<html>` `your code` `</html>`. Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь JQuery:

```
var shrink = function () {
    $(this).effect("scale", {percent: 40}, 1000, grow);
};

var grow = function () {
    $(this).effect("scale", {percent: 250}, 1000, shrink);
};

$("img").click(shrink);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"> </script>
<script src="jquery.tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tonus').tooltip({
    delay: 0,
    showURL: false,
    bodyHandler: function() {
        return $("<img/>").attr("src", this.src);
    }
});

</script>
```

Ну-с вот при наведении (взято с гугла).

Comment: Спасибо! я так понимаю jquery надо скачать? Честно говоря, я не прошарен в html...